# How to tell to what file.txt stdout is redirected?

Tags: java, bash

**Context:** I was told to use commands of the form  `System.out.println()` in any `Java` class I create to log the progress of the class in use (i.e. at runtime).

The content of the `"()"` gets written to a text file which can be inspected later. But where precisely is that log?

The admin defined its name and location (i.e. fully qualified path) two years ago, but I have forgotten the definition, and would like to find it without asking the admin. How can I look up (in the ksh command line) where System.out.println() gets written?

How can I create such a definition in the bash command line? 
-- The definition appears to retain its effect across logins. -- A couple of hours of googling have not answered these outrageously elementary questions.

Comment: First and foremost using `System.out` for logging in enterprise environments it not acceptable and should never be done; a real logging framework should be used. Now, with that off my chest, `System.out` is written to `STDOUT` on your TTY. How do you start the program? There is probably a redirect in the bootstrapping script.

Comment: Are you running on Linux?  If so, take a look at `ls -l /proc/$$/fd`

Answer (score 1):

Use ps -edf command to show what processes are running in your system, then maybe you can see the output redirection.

Another useful tool, lsof (list open files). It will show you which files are opened in your system. One of them must be your log